# Custom slider thumb selectable region incorrect with custom slider track

Tags: flutter, dart

In my custom slider thumb and track, the incorrect region of the slider thumb is selectable for dragging. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 100),
            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 100),
              CustomSlider()
            ])
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}


class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSliderState createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  double _value = .5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
        data: SliderThemeData(
          thumbShape: _SliderThumbImage(),
          trackShape: _SliderTrack(), // Commenting results in correct selectable thumb region
        ),
        child: Slider(
          min: .1, max: 1, value: _value,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() { _value = value; })
        ));
  }
}

class _SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {
  static const thumbSideLength = 60.0;
  
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required bool isDiscrete, required TextPainter labelPainter, required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required double value, required double textScaleFactor, required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;

    Offset thumbDrawOffset = Offset(center.dx - (thumbSideLength / 2), center.dy - (thumbSideLength / 2));

    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(thumbDrawOffset.dx, thumbDrawOffset.dy, thumbSideLength, thumbSideLength),
                    Paint()..color = Colors.black);
  }

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size(thumbSideLength, thumbSideLength);
  }
}

class _SliderTrack extends SliderTrackShape {
  static const width = 184.0;
  static const trackHeight = 16.0;

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect(
      {required RenderBox parentBox, Offset offset = Offset.zero, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, bool isEnabled = true, bool isDiscrete = true}) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, width, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset,
      {required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required Offset thumbCenter, bool isEnabled = true, bool isDiscrete = true, required TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;

    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy + trackHeight / 2),
        Offset(offset.dx + width, offset.dy + trackHeight / 2),
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.amber
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..strokeWidth = trackHeight);
  }
}
```

This renders the following. The top half of the black square is not selectable for dragging whereas the entire bottom half of the slider is selectable. Either the top half of the slider or the slider thumb should be selectable.

[image]

If I comment out the `trackShape` parameter, the correct region of the thumb is selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region of the slider that is selectable for the purpose of adjusting slider value is configured by both the track dimensions and thumb dimensions. If you configure the thumb to be 50x50 and the track to be 100x10, the area that is selectable is the 50x100 bounding box of the slider, not the 50x50 thumb area. For example, the area highlighted below is the selectable area:
[image]

That is also the behavior for the default slider without a theme.

With that in mind, I drew the track and thumb offset appropriately within this bounding box.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const thumbSideLength = 60.0;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 100),
            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 100),
              CustomSlider()
            ])
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}


class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSliderState createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  double _value = .5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
        data: SliderThemeData(
          thumbShape: _SliderThumbImage(),
          trackShape: _SliderTrack(), // Commenting results in correct selectable thumb region
        ),
        child: Slider(
          min: .1, max: 1, value: _value,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() { _value = value; })
        ));
  }
}

class _SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {  
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required bool isDiscrete, required TextPainter labelPainter, required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required double value, required double textScaleFactor, required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    Offset thumbCenter = Offset(center.dx, thumbSideLength/2);

    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromCenter(center: thumbCenter, width: thumbSideLength, height: thumbSideLength), Paint()..color = Colors.black);
  }

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size(thumbSideLength, thumbSideLength);
  }
}

class _SliderTrack extends SliderTrackShape {
  static const width = 184.0;
  static const trackHeight = 16.0;

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect(
      {required RenderBox parentBox, Offset offset = Offset.zero, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, bool isEnabled = true, bool isDiscrete = true}) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, width, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset,
      {required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required Offset thumbCenter, bool isEnabled = true, bool isDiscrete = true, required TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy + thumbSideLength/2),
      Offset(offset.dx + width, offset.dy + thumbSideLength / 2),
      Paint()
      ..color = Colors.amber
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = trackHeight);
  }
}
```